# asp.net core after ajax call model is null

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to add elements after an ajax call to the server to a list that isnt static.

```
public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

            public async Task OnGetUserId(string id, string categoryId)
            {
...
                langResults = new List<LangResult>();
            }
```

This is my only constructor in my app, it creates a new instance of the list.

My ajax call calls my controller:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Jobs/Sprachen/?handler=RemoveLanguage",
                data: { "LangName": langName, "LangQuality": langQuality, "LangNeccessity": langNecc },
                headers:
                {
                    "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
```

and the controller is supposed to add elements to the list:

```
public IActionResult OnPostAddLanguage(LangResult input)
        {
            // called from ajax (no page reload) 
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest("Invalid model");
            langResults.Add(input);
            return new JsonResult(input);
        }
```

the problem however is, is that thelist is now null and no longer instantiated.

I could make the list static but thats not what I wish to do as I want that instance only to exist while the user is on that one page.

How can I instantiate my list once and then never again but also have it never be 0?

Best,

J